# How to match mongoid documents using array fields in query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to match documents with Mongoid/Mongodb where array fields are used in the query. I've been struggling with `$elemMatch` but can't seem to get it.

### Context

- A `Project` can have `admin`, `member`, `reader` users
- These users are referenced by a `Project` (HABTM)
- I want to be able to find projects where:

  - User A is `admin`
  - User B is `admin` or `member`
  - .. etc ..

### Example

Given a `Project` document from Rails console:

```
[#<Project _id: 4f44355a9f5b7f385a000003, 
  _type: nil, name: "Project ABC", 
  desc: "some description", 
  admin_ids: 
    [BSON::ObjectId('123')], 
  member_ids: 
    [BSON::ObjectId('456'),
    BSON::ObjectId('789')], 
  reader_ids: []
>]
```

I had the following code:

```
@projects = Project.any_of({:admin_ids => [current_user.id]}, 
                           {:member_ids => [current_user.id]}).entries
```

Which matches `current_user.id` across either `admin_ids` and `member_ids` *as long as* there was only a single value in either of the arrays. As per the code above:

- Trying to match user `'123'` gives correct result
- Trying to match user `'456'` gives no result (incorrect)

### $elemMatch

**Based on researching, I think I should be using `$elemMatch` but am missing something.**

As per the `Project` document code above:

```
// test case: this works with array of one
Project.all(conditions: {:admin_ids => "123"}).entries

// failure case: empty result   
Project.all(conditions: {:member_ids => {'$elemMatch' => {:id => '456' } }}).entries

// failure case: empty result
Project.all(conditions: {:member_ids => {'$elemMatch' => {:id => BSON::ObjectId('4f44a4019f5b7f3d5200000d') } }}).entries
```

Comment: I think you should just be able to use `$in` rather than `$elemMatch` - as the mongodocs say: "You only need to use this when more than one field must be matched in the array element."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to get rid of the array while querying.

```
@projects = Project.any_of({:admin_ids => current_user.id}, 
                       {:member_ids => current_user.id}).entries
```

That should work.

Comment: for some reason I had to explicitly cast the `current_user.id`  to a string with `to_s` for this to work in a scope.

Answer (score 11):

I think you should just be able to use `$in` rather than $elemMatch - as the [mongodocs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries) say:

> "You only need to use [`$elemMatch`] when more than one field must be matched in
>   the array element."

Have you tried something like the following?

```
Project.any_in(:member_ids =>  [ member_id_one, member_id_two ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification around `$elemMatch`. Yeah, I needed to have something more like @rubish's code.

Comment: Alternatively you can do:

Project.where(:member_ids.in =>  [ member_id_one, member_id_two ])